# Reporting Services Issues when deploying to server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I created some SQL Server Reporting Services reports using Microsoft Visual Studio. Previewing the reports is working fine. But when i deploy the application, i get the following errors: **The permissions granted to user 'PERSOLGH\SOMAD' are insufficient for performing this operation**.
But the SQL Server Management Studio Reporting Services works fine.
What could cause the error or am I missing something?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Best Regards,
Somad

Comment: Are you getting the error when deploying the report, or when viewing the report?  in the folder in question does domain\username have publisher rights?

Comment: You can use visual studio to develop reports that will be working fine when previewing, but as Jerry has mentioned, deploying to the report server requires the proper permissions

Comment: I have solved the issue but i have another problem. The issue is I have right access to the report folder but the report is not loading